# Sqlite3 installation stuck in "unpacking node_sqlite3.node"

Tags: node.js, npm, sqlite, npm-install

I was reinstalling packages for my project and while I was installing all the packages, it gets stuck in:

```
> sqlite3@3.1.13 install C:\Users\RAP\Desktop\bots\mei-discord\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

Since it's been like that for minutes, I deleted node_modules again and attempted to reinstall the packages with `--loglevel verbose` enabled. So far this what happened and after 30 minutes, it's stuck there: https://hastebin.com/obuwetoduj.rb (Logs is too long)

But the end of the logs is this:

```
npm info lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.13~install: sqlite3@3.1.13

> sqlite3@3.1.13 install C:\Users\RAP\Desktop\bots\mei-discord\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\RAP\\Desktop\\bots\\mei-discord\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   'install',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   '--fallback-to-build' ]
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.38
node-pre-gyp info using node@8.11.1 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp verb command install []
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\RAP\Desktop\bots\mei-discord\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 200 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp info install unpacking node_sqlite3.node
```

(I included the full log above if I missed something)

I've done other things like reinstalling build tools for node-gyp, reinstalling node-pre-gyp but nothing work, still stuck in that state without returning any error or any log output.

Here's my system information:

- OS: Windows 10 (64-bit)
- Node: v8.11.1
- NPM: 5.6.0

I've opened an issue in sqlite3's repo but I though of asking the issue here as well.

So my question is why it went stuck in that part and what caused it, and what's the solution for it.

Comment: Triggered by the `v57` in `sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz`, while you're using Node 8, I checked the [sqlite3 npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) and it only claims compatibility up to version 7. Might just be they've not updated the page, might be the part of the problem.

Comment: Can't really use node v7 because my package `discord.js-commando` requires node 8 and sqlite is used for a setting provider. Since sqlite3 is a dependency of sqlite, I need to install that as well and then this stuff happens

Comment: I was just pointing out a possible anomaly, in case it helped you (or someone else) home in on the problem. But if discord needs Node 8 and uses sqlite; and sqlite needs sqlite3, then that suggests sqlite3 probably _does_ work with Node 8, the NPM page is out of date, and Something Else™ is happening.

Comment: Honestly sqlite isn't a dependency for discord.js-commando but the documentation recommends sqlite for settings provider